# yx5200-24ss mp3 player schematic

Tags: microcontroller, mp3

i'm sorry for asking a stupid question, but currently i'm making a simple mp3 player with yx5200-24ss chip. Please read the attached schematic below:

[image: Schematic]

Is it alright if i'm not using pin 15 and pin 16 (adkey1 and adkey2) as shown in the schematic above? For i plan on using mcu to control the ic. Will it working properly without a 22k resistor between vdd io and the addkeys pins?

By the way this ic used in [DFPlayer Mini](https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/DFPlayer_Mini_SKU:DFR0299)

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it alright if i'm not using pin 15 and pin 16 (adkey1 and adkey2) as shown in the schematic above? For i plan on using mcu to control the ic. Will it working properly without a 22k resistor between vdd io and the addkeys pins?

If you aren't going to implement any of the keys, then the value of the pull-up resistor isn't critical, but you still need something to keep the line high. If it's allowed to float, the chip may read errant key presses.

You *might* even be able to get away with connecting ADKEY1/2 directly to the 3.3V rail, but I'd be a little wary of doing that.